# Finding base with respect for the given transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have given base $\alpha = (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1) $. I should create base $\beta$ so that matrix $M$:

$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)
$

1) Is transformation matrix from base $\alpha$ to base $\beta$
$$$$
2) Is transformation matrix from base $\beta$ to base $\alpha$

Comment: You should ask Mark Teixeira. But make sure you do it politely. Find the base with respect.

Answer (score 1):

The first is easy, you want $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$ such that $M \alpha_i = \beta_i$, so you just need to multiply each $\alpha_i$ by the matrix $M$.

For the second part you can do it by computing the inverse matrix $M^{-1}$ and taking $\beta_i = M^{-1} \alpha_i$, for then $M \beta_i = \alpha_i$ is the required transformation property.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b$ the standard basis so the transformation matrix from $b$ to the basis $\alpha$ is
$$
T_b^\alpha=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1\end{array} \right)
$$
where the columns of $T_b^\alpha$ are the vectors of $\alpha$. Now the matrix $M$ is the transformation matrix from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ so it is

$$M=T_\alpha^\beta=T_\alpha^b T_b^\beta=\left(T_b^\alpha\right)^{-1}T_b^\beta\implies T_b^\beta=T_b^\alpha M$$
and the column of $T_b^\beta$ are the vectors of the basis $\beta$. Can you by the similar way answer the second question?